# In CouchbaseLite does LiveQuery changeListener get triggered when a document is deleted?

Tags: java, android, database, couchbase-lite

I am trying to listen to document changes using live query and I have some operations which is based on this live query and on the assumption that the live query is triggered on document delete also. I just wanted to confirm if that is the case before I start implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, live queries trigger the ChangeDelegate on deletion. When a document is deleted, it isn't actually deleted from the database, changed to a [tombstone](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.5/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/revision/index.html).